# MySQL - update all records to match last

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction table like so

```
id , name , code  ,  flag 
1 ,  john , 1234-3,   2
2 ,  joe  , 1111-2,   1
3 ,  paul , 1234-3,   3
4 ,  asdf , 1234-3,   3
5 ,  asdf , 1111-2,   5
6 ,  asdf , 1234-3,   8
```

Basically, what I want to do is get the last instance of a code check the flag and update all previous flags with the same code with the last flag num.

So in in the case of code 1234-3 it should update all flags with that code with flag num 8
in the case of 1111-2, it needs to update all flags with that code with 5.

I want to transform it into this table

```
id , name , code  ,  flag 
1 ,  john , 1234-3,   8
2 ,  joe  , 1111-2,   5
3 ,  paul , 1234-3,   8
4 ,  asdf , 1234-3,   8
5 ,  asdf , 1111-2,   5
6 ,  asdf , 1234-3,   8
```

I'd like to do this in MySQL purely if possible.  There is a very large set of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE  t_transaction tu
JOIN    (
        SELECT  tm.code, tm.flag
        FROM    (
                SELECT  code, MAX(id) AS id
                FROM    t_transaction
                GROUP BY
                        code
                ) td
        JOIN    t_transaction tm
        ON      tm.id = td.id
        ) t
ON      tu.code = t.code
SET     tu.flag = t.flag
```

Make sure you have an index on `(code)`, if your table is `InnoDB` **and** `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, or on `(code, id)` if your table is `MyISAM` **or** `id` is not a `PRIMARY KEY`.

This index will be used both both for `JOIN`'s and for efficient `GROUP BY`.

To set the value to the `MAX(flag)` (not the last `flag`):

```
UPDATE  t_transaction tu
JOIN    (
        SELECT  code, MAX(flag) AS flag
        FROM    t_transaction
        GROUP BY
                code
        ) t
ON      tu.code = t.code
SET     tu.flag = t.flag
```

Comment: intersting, just to understand what your doing;  Are you joining the table to itself?

Comment: would it be a good idea when doing an update like this to have indices to speed up the query?  2 million rows

Comment: wow, this took me quite awhile to get it! the inner most select to get last/max id, 2nd to get the flag, 3rd to set flag by join with code. something like that

Comment: cheers @Quassnoi... that worked perfectly on 100k rows.. the 2million row table may take a long time but very nicely done!

any thoughts on this one: http://short.ie/i9estp

Comment: @Quassnoi If on the above one, I wanted to set it to the max code instead of the code in that is the last instance.  how would i do that?